# Functionatlity of Open NFC Framework

Tags: nfc, open-nfc

I have fundamental question about what Open NFC framework is for. I want to write a program that will run on a PC to communicate with a NFC card reader connected to the PC through USB. The program will write to and read from NFC tags by commanding the NFC card reader.

Is Open NFC framework suited for this purpose? Or is it for developing programs that will run on NFC tags?

Aritra

Answer (score 2):

OpenNFC is a software stack implementing NFC functionalities. 
It is hardware independent, so in theory you could use it with an USB connected reader. The problem is, the only available HALs (Hardware Abstraction Layers) for OpenNFC are for an NFC simulator and Inside Secure hardware. Until we get some HALs for most common hardware, I'd say you should take look at http://www.libnfc.org/documentation/introduction

Answer (score 1):

There are many NFC readers on the market, that are being sold with their own SDKs. With such SDKs you are 100% sure the code is compatible with the particular NFC reader.

BR
STeN